# How to modify DB field on a given date, if this field depends on another field

Tags: java, spring, postgresql

Java, Spring, PostgresDB

I want to set TRUE isActive column in the Subscription table automatically, if the subscriptionStartDate hits the actual date.
A scheduled task to check the startDate every subscription every day seems to be little raw solution (but maybe the only).
Any better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are requesting to mutate the value of a column without explicitly require the database change. This is not supported by PostgresDB/MySQL.
With this approach some scheduled task is required.

Although you can take a different approach, when you retrieve the records you can search by  `subscriptionStartDate <= now()`  which will get all subscriptions that are currently active.